# define variable using conditional statement in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table "products" with columns like:

```
| price | discount_price | start_discount | end_discount | ... |
```

*start_discount and end_discount is a UNIX timestamp

Current price of a product depends on time - if '**time()**' is between '**start_discount**' and '**end_discount**' then the *current price* is '**discount_price**', otherwise is '**price**'

I am trying to return "**current_price**" variable. In PHP, I would just write:

```
$current_price = (time() > $start_discount && time() < $end_discount)? $discount_price : $price;
```

How can I achieve the same as above in MySQL without involving PHP?

I have this so far:

```
SELECT *, (**price OR discount_price**) as current_price FROM products WHERE active = 1 AND current_price BETWEEN '100' AND '200' ORDER BY current_price;
```

Comment: Make sure to describe in your question the orphaned code at the end .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, I am only selecting the price you can select whatever you want from the table

```
select
case when
 now() > start_discount AND now() < end_discount then discount_price
else price end as current_price
from 
products 
WHERE 
active = 1 
AND price BETWEEN '100' AND '200'
ORDER BY current_price
```

EDIT :
Just noticed you are using `current_price` in the where condition, which you can not do since its an alias so you may need to use a table column in the where clause or use `having` clause as

```
select
case when
 now() > start_discount AND now() < end_discount then discount_price
else price end as current_price
from 
products 
WHERE 
active = 1 
having current_price BETWEEN '100' AND '200'
ORDER BY current_price
```

Here is a test I did

```
mysql> create table products (price int, discount_price int ,start_discount date ,end_discount date);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into products values (100,60,'2014-10-01','2014-11-01'),(200,160,'2014-10-01','2014-10-10'),(300,200,'2014-11-01','2014-11-15');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select case when  now() > start_discount AND now() < end_discount then discount_price else price end as current_price from  products order by current_price;
+---------------+
| current_price |
+---------------+
|            60 |
|           200 |
|           300 |
+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Looks promising - but I have just tested it and current_price is returning 'price' on 'discount_price' products

Comment: Check my update I just did a test and it works, make sure your `start_discount` and `end_discount` is in proper data type `date,datetime or timestamp`

Comment: That was the problem :) my date is in UNIX timestamp so I have to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() instead of now(), thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an IF statement in mySQL

```
select id, name,
  if(startDiscount_at <= now() && endDiscount_at > now(), discountPrice, price) as current_price
from products
  where active = 1
  having current_price between 100 and 200
  order by current_price;
```

[Link to SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cca91/2)

Comment: I have tested your answer as well and it is working too :) thanks